# Membership period with multiple terms not working in paypal payment page

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, payment-processor, paypal

I have a membership type A and B with following configuration:

- no auto-renew option
- duration: 1 month
- period type: rolling
- visibility: public

I set multiple price set, each price set have different price options for both membership type A and B.

For example:
Price set for location X:

- 1 month membership A
- 3 months membership A
- 6 months membership A
- 12 months membership A
- 3 months membership B

In each price option, the number of terms is set accordingly (1,3,6 or 12).

The problem I'm facing is:

When user filling in the CiviContribute form, select one of the price option and pay through PayPal, the membership end date does not follow the terms, and show end date as 1 month after payment date.

Example: User select "6 months membership A" and make payment, the membership end date is 1 month later, rather than 6 months.

I tried payment using test payment page and pay through paypal sandbox, the membership end date is 1 months later.

I tried make payment through "Pay Later" option, update payment status to complete through CiviContribute dashboard, and membership end date is 6 months later.

I'm not sure how to debug and what I can do to solve this. Any suggestion?

UPDATE: this issue was resolved (see Comment): "I upgraded CiviCRM to version 4.6.11 and it works. Thank you for your help!"

Comment: I have a site with a very similar configuration that works correctly.  Can you please post screenshots of your price set configuration page?

Comment: Price set setting: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNeIN-HQDoxlBo2DrPungEHcE8nRheyXGV4FlSygxWBn9eKf0y_5YC8Qh7ez-XZQQ?key=WHh5VDZuenFLbVZpU3hXQkpZZXZzYU4zR1pKSUl3

Comment: Price option setting: https://goo.gl/photos/dogFr9zxGCbEwPii8

Comment: Those are both the same image.

Comment: Oh oh sorry I paste a duplicate link, This is the correct one https://goo.gl/photos/jZbMUJuJSxGS4hd8A

Comment: Anyway, I upgraded CiviCRM to version 4.6.11 and it works. Thank you for your help!